# Failed to resolve: com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer- smoothstreaming:2.9.1

Tags: java, android, video, stream, exoplayer

I am trying to create a simple video player android app with exoplayer.

I found a couple of examples like:

https://github.com/brianwernick/ExoMedia/?

https://github.com/ayalus/ExoPlayer-2-Example?

https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer?

However when I try to build and run the projects, I keep getting the same error:

> Failed to resolve: com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer- 
>      smoothstreaming:2.9.1
>   Install Repository and sync project
>   Open File
>   Show in Project Structure dialog

I am using the latest version of the android studio and when click on "Install Repository and sync project" It gives the following error message:

```
"Could not find dependency "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-smoothstreaming:2.9.1""
```

I don't know how to solve the problem. If you can share a simple player example that can also work for me.

Answer (score 2):

With Google sunsetting `jcenter` in 2022, `exoplayer` now has to install exclusively from Google Maven, aka `google`, which is also the recommended way to install according to their Github page.

It appears however some older versions of `exoplayer`, e.g. `v2.9.x`, only exists on `jcenter`. This could be a problem if your app is migrating away from `jcenter` as Google recommended. The problem would easily go away if you install `exoplayer`'s latest version, `v15`.

My suggestion is if you are already considering deprecating the old `jcenter`, you might as well update `exoplayer` to its latest version.

Answer (score 1):

the exoplayer dependency  should now be available on jcenter(). Please let us know if you still run into any issues. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120759347#comment97.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you missed type for your dependency :

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android.exoplayer</groupId>
            <artifactId>exoplayer-smoothstreaming</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
```

You should also add a repo that contain this artifact (maven.google.com for example) to your repositories in order to fetch it.

```
   <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>android-studio</id>
            <url>https://maven.google.com</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

for gradle refer to https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer

Answer (score 0):

Changing the gradle file as follows solved the problem

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/' }
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools' }
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/firebase/gradle/' }
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }

}
```